# Assign a query result to an object inside a controller

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core-mvc

I searched for this solution but haven't found exactly what i'm looking for. I'm using code first entity framework MVC on Visual Studio 2017 and have a Clubs table, Student table and a link Members table. Each club has a number of members. Each student can be a member of a number of clubs. What i'm looking to do is count the number of students that are associated with each club inside the clubs controller. I have a field TotalMembers in the Clubs table to hold this value. I want to then display the result in the Clubs view. This is my code so far. Any help is welcome.

My clubs controller

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string searchString)
        {
            //count how many members each club has
            var count = (from m in _context.Members
                         join c in _context.Clubs
                         on m.ClubID equals c.Id
                         select m.StudentID).ToList().Count();

            ViewData["CurrentFilter"] = searchString;
            var clubs = from c in _context.Clubs
                        select c;



            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                clubs = clubs.Where(c => c.Name.Contains(searchString));
            }

            return View(await clubs.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync());
        }
```

And my club index.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<ClubsAndSocieties.Models.Club>
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}
<h2 class="text-center pageHeading">Current Clubs and Societies</h2>

<form asp-action="Index" method="get">
    <div class="form-actions no-color">
        <p>
            <a asp-action="Create" id="addClass" class="btn btn-info btn-md">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Add
            </a>
            <input type="text" placeholder=" Find by name:" name="SearchString" value="@ViewData["currentFilter"]" />
            <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-group-sm" />

            <a asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-info btn-md">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span> Full List
            </a>
        </p>
    </div>
</form>
<div style="overflow-x:auto;">
    <table class="responstable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
                </th>

                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Chairperson)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Secretary)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Treasurer)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Phone)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TotalMembers)
                </th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Chairperson)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Secretary)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Treasurer)
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Phone)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TotalMembers)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id" class="btn btn-info btn-md edit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Edit</a>
                        <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id" class="btn btn-info btn-md details"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> Details</a>
                        <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id" class="btn btn-info btn-md delete"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Delete</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**My goal is to get the result of the count variable to be placed inside the clubs and returned so I can display it in the clubs view as "TotalMembers"**

Comment: What is the problem here? Are you getting any exception?

Comment: I want the result of the count variable to be placed inside the clubs and returned so I can display it in the clubs view as "TotalMembers" . No execption because I haven't used the "count" variable yet.

Comment: You don't have to use `ToList()` while using `Count()` at this line `.ToList().Count();`. Only use `Count()`. Also you need to set count inside that model by running `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first, your query just counts all members. The join is actually pretty pointless. If you want to count members per club, you need a group by clause and group by something like the club id or name.

The model you're sending to the view is simply an `IEnumerable<Club>` so there's not really any place to add the counts. You would either need to use a view model, where you can add a property for the count, or simply add the counts to a `ViewBag` member. In your view, then, you can pull out the count for a particular club from this as you iterate over your list of clubs.

Comment: Can you give me an example how to do this. Im new to linq and MVC